# Regular expression in pyspark to check alphabets and space (Also work with uni codes)

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need a regular expression which validates below table.

[image]

It should return valid only when the string has alphabets or alphabets with space.

I tried below codes but it is not allowing space.

`r = "\A\pL+\z"`

`Result_Name =  Name_NotNull.withColumn("Name_Alphabets_Valid", when(col("first").rlike(r), lit("valid")).otherwise(lit("Invalid")))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am checking it in the code only `col("first").rlike(r), lit("valid")` using **rlike**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a character class which admits whitespace in addition to alpha characters:

```
r = "\A[\pL\s]+\z"
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked . I will check all the string and let you know if I get any doubt.

Comment: I am doing email validation using r = `"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"` but its returning some valid email ids as invalid example **MAayeri@zadco.ae** and **baamirnting@icloud.com**  , Can you please have a look and guid me.

Comment: If you need help with another (email) regex, you should open a new question.

Comment: Okay I will post my question